Jetty threads getting blocked in response timeout testing causing application crash
I'm testing a traffic scenario with TPS of ~1000, the HTTP/2 server has a high delay hence all the message send by Jetty HTTP/2 client to the server gets timed out. Below is my observation with this run. I'm using Jetty's HttpClient with Spring WebFlux's reactive client (WebClient).

1000+ Jetty threads are created
Among them ~200 threads were in blocked state (traceback added below)
The application becomes unresponsive at this stage and eventually dies (OOM)

Request:
I encountered an uncaught exception in the system, and I'm reaching out for clarification on the underlying cause. The stacktrace attached below shows the thread is blocked while attempting to acquire a lock on the PrintStream object. Could you help clarify what might be causing this blockage? Is there a specific condition or known issue that could lead to this uncaught exception?
Stacktrace of blocked thread:
"@365a6a43-660" #660 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.79ms elapsed=0.90s tid=0x0000559958d13150 nid=0x16bb waiting for monitor entry  [0x00007f96e6bfc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.io.PrintStream.write(java.base@17.0.7/PrintStream.java:696)
        - waiting to lock <0x0000000680c98068> (a java.io.PrintStream)
        at java.io.PrintStream.print(java.base@17.0.7/PrintStream.java:863)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(java.base@17.0.7/ThreadGroup.java:1084)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(java.base@17.0.7/ThreadGroup.java:1077)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers.handleError(Schedulers.java:1208)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.ExecutorScheduler.schedule(ExecutorScheduler.java:70)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.trySchedule(MonoPublishOn.java:146)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.onNext(MonoPublishOn.java:120)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.java:74)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onError(FluxTimeout.java:219)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2063)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:544)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:56)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:278)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.reactive.client.internal.AbstractSingleProcessor.onError(AbstractSingleProcessor.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.reactive.client.internal.ResponseListenerProcessor.onComplete(ResponseListenerProcessor.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:477)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.abort(HttpReceiver.java:553)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpChannel.abortResponse(HttpChannel.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.terminateRequest(HttpSender.java:298)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.abortRequest(HttpSender.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.abort(HttpSender.java:385)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.lambda$executeAbort$0(HttpSender.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender$$Lambda$2278/0x0000000801a3a400.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:894)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1038)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@17.0.7/Thread.java:833)

Stacktrace of thread blocking the PrintStream

"@365a6a43-659" #659 prio=5 os\_prio=0 cpu=0.91ms elapsed=0.90s tid=0x00007f97186787d0 nid=0x16ba runnable  \[0x00007f96e6cfd000\]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.lang.StackTraceElement.initStackTraceElements(java.base@17.0.7/Native Method)
at java.lang.StackTraceElement.of(java.base@17.0.7/StackTraceElement.java:541)
at java.lang.Throwable.getOurStackTrace(java.base@17.0.7/Throwable.java:839)
- locked \<0x00000007928193e0> (a java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(java.base@17.0.7/Throwable.java:701)
at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(java.base@17.0.7/Throwable.java:682)
- locked \<0x0000000680c98068> (a java.io.PrintStream)
at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(java.base@17.0.7/Throwable.java:659)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(java.base@17.0.7/ThreadGroup.java:1086)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(java.base@17.0.7/ThreadGroup.java:1077)
at reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers.handleError(Schedulers.java:1208)
at reactor.core.scheduler.ExecutorScheduler.schedule(ExecutorScheduler.java:70)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.trySchedule(MonoPublishOn.java:146)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.onNext(MonoPublishOn.java:120)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.java:74)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onError(FluxTimeout.java:219)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2063)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:544)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:56)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:278)
at org.eclipse.jetty.reactive.client.internal.AbstractSingleProcessor.onError(AbstractSingleProcessor.java:120)
at org.eclipse.jetty.reactive.client.internal.ResponseListenerProcessor.onComplete(ResponseListenerProcessor.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:205)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:477)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:457)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.abort(HttpReceiver.java:553)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpChannel.abortResponse(HttpChannel.java:149)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.terminateRequest(HttpSender.java:298)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.abortRequest(HttpSender.java:280)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.abort(HttpSender.java:385)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.lambda$executeAbort$0(HttpSender.java:252)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender$$Lambda$2278/0x0000000801a3a400.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:894)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1038)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@17.0.7/Thread.java:833)

Locked ownable synchronizers:


Reactor version(s) used: 3.5.14
Other relevant libraries versions (eg. netty, ...): Jetty 11.0.11
JVM version (java -version): 17.0.7
OS and version (eg uname -a): Linux
I expect the traffic to be sent continuously. While it may fail due to high server delays, the application itself should not crash.

If you're submitting a bug report I don't think that the SO is a right place. Better to submit them to the Reactor's Github directly.

btw, for 1000 TPS you don't usually need more than 10-50 threads

Where do you see your application crashing? The thread stacks you presented only show that the threads are trying to write to stderr which is a serialization point for your many threads and no actual application crash in the traditional sense. Have you tried to redirect stderr to /dev/null to improve performance for writing to stderr? You can also implement proper error handling so that the uncaught exception handler doesn't need to write to stderr in the first place.

Are you running in Kubernetes or a containerized environment? You might be getting OOM due to insufficient non-heap memory even though the heap size is below limits
